# Super queen strategy with level 1 archer queen?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Can a level 1 archer queen and 14 healers implement the Super Queen strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need that number of healers, because you have to strike the balance between having your archer queen combo and other troops. There are two reasons why this strategy works better with a higher level archer queen: the archer queen has more health and thus can go in and out of dangerous situations easier, and the archer queen has a high DPS so she can destroy a fair portion of a base in a fair amount of time.

A level 1 archer queen however has neither of these. What could happen if you try to compensate the lack of heal with more healers is running out of time because the archer queen has not brought enough of the base down. Plus without her ability, she's even more vulnerable, for example against high damage defensive CC troops like maxed balloons, dragons and pekkas (if you ever encounter that one) because I'm pretty sure they can knock her out pretty quickly even with healers healing her.

So all in all, yes it can be done, but I would say that you have a really low chance of success (of course, at least against a good TH9 base).

Answer (score 1):

This strategy has been nerfed in the recent clash of clans update. Any number of healers past 5 or 6 on the same unit has diminishing returns; basically, don't bring much more than 7 or 8 EVER now because 15 healers now heals the same as 7 or 8 anyways because of steep deminishing returns. Plus, 7 or 8 probably doesn't do much more healing than around 5 or 6.

One more thing to add about the strategy, you can actually bring rage potions and rage the queen AND HEALERS. Healers heal faster while under rage, and this is now very important to use in this strategy since you won't be able to bring as many healers. Jump spells and/or lots of bombers are commonly used in this strategy to get the queen to go where you want her to go sooner, since time is a big part of this strategy.

Also, as a general rule, the superqueen strategy requires around a lvl 20 to start being effective at townhall 9, and this is even more true now after the update. This is a general guideline and you can go lower, it just won't be as good as other competing strategies, but it can still be fun! Once you get your queen to around 25 it actually becomes of the best farming strategies there is at TH9.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that multiple healers now incur diminishing returns.

Answer (score 0):

The Super Queen strategy consists of mainly one Archer Queen and lots of healers. So yes, yes you can. Any other troops added are variations of the strategy and will still be the Super Archer Queen strategy though it is mainly used with high level Archer Queens and low-level bases.